# How to select n no. of events and compare all events?

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

By doing correlation between incoming events, we can do some calculations with past data based on specified time-frame.
[As mentioned here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Correlating+Events+for+Complex+Event+Processing).

I'm doing something like this to receive events based on some specified time frame by using `within` keyword.

`@info(name='dg-start-check-query') 
from every (e1=InputStream) -> e2=InputStream[e1.meter_id=='s1' and e2.meter_id=='s1' and convert(e2.current_avg, 'double')-convert(e1.current_avg, 'double')==convert(e2.current_avg, 'double') and convert(e1.current_avg, 'double')+convert(e2.current_avg, 'double')!=0 and convert(e1.current_avg, 'double')==0]
within 1 min
select time:dateFormat(e2.device_time, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS yyyy-MM-dd') as date_time
insert into OutputStreamStarted;`

How can I let this code to just receive past 2 or 3 events and do calculations over it just like events are collected using `window`?
This code will receive all events within given timeframe and get executed multiple times if multiple events satisfies its criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [defined length window](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#defined-window) to achieve this requirement. For each incoming event perform [unidirectional join](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#join-stream) with the window and then later put into window. Your conditions can go into on condition of the join. Sample query is given below. You will need to work on your logical conditions as those need improvement.

```
define stream InputStream (meter_id string, current_avg string, device_time int); 
define window eventWindow (meter_id string, current_avg string, device_time int) length(2); 

@info(name = 'query1') from InputStream[meter_id=='s1']#window.length(1) as e1 unidirectional join eventWindow as e2 
on (convert(e2.current_avg, 'double')-convert(e1.current_avg, 'double')==convert(e2.current_avg, 'double')) 
select e1.device_time insert into OutputStreamStarted ; 

@info(name = 'query2') from InputStream[meter_id=='s1'] 
select meter_id, current_avg, device_time 
insert into eventWindow ;
```